# Install pandas 0.23.3 on python 3.7.6 report ‘NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘NPY_INOUT_ARRAY’

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to install pandas 0.23.3 on top of python 3.7.6 to migrate an application from x86 container to s390x container. But unfortunately, it failed with below error. I also tried other closer versions such as pandas 0.23.4 till pandas 0.25.3, all gave me above errors.

What could be the reasons?
Could anyone kindly give some clue?

Appreciate for the help!!!

```
root@45697611ec40:/# python --version
Python 3.7.6
root@45697611ec40:/# pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
root@45697611ec40:/#
root@45697611ec40:/# pip install Cython==0.29.36
Collecting Cython==0.29.36
  Downloading Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 988 kB 64.4 MB/s
Installing collected packages: Cython
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.36
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
root@45697611ec40:/#
root@45697611ec40:/# pip install pandas==0.23.3
Collecting pandas==0.23.3
  Downloading pandas-0.23.3.tar.gz (10.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.5 MB 15.7 MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 247 kB 83.4 MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2011k
  Downloading pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 502 kB 61.4 MB/s

.............

    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c: In function ‘initObjToJSON’:
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:193:12: error: ‘NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘NPY_INOUT_ARRAY’?
         return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                NPY_INOUT_ARRAY
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:193:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c: In function ‘PyUnicodeToUTF8’:
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:429:22: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
             char *data = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(obj, &len);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:435:5: warning: ‘PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         newObj = PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(obj),
         ^~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:99,
                     from pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/py_defines.h:41,
                     from pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:42:
    /usr/local/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:1320:23: note: declared here
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c: In function ‘initObjToJSON’:
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:194:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m3me78e_/pandas/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m3me78e_/pandas/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-23v8v76f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
root@45697611ec40:/#

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Details, kindly refer below log:

<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i0awjelhcz1izl92ifpah/pandas_install.log?rlkey=taxh9hdtq8dy2gvyn8l40ugvo&dl=0">pandas_install.log</a>




I had tried to install pandas 0.23.4 till pandas 0.25.3, all got the same error.
```